# Meaning of the statement "Are you playing thick or just are? "

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquialisms

Somebody told me

> Are you playing thick or just are?

in the middle of a conversation. and I didn't know its meaning. I searched for "**play thick**" in Google, but I didn't find anything.

1. Is “are you playing thick” slang?
2. What does it mean?

Comment: What context is this expression used in? May be that can shed some light on its usage. Personally, I have never heard of such usage.

Comment: General background is "criticizing".

Comment: "Are you being thick?" is more like it. Or how about "Are you thick or just playing?"

Comment: In the United States, the (equivalently hostile) wording might be "Are you just playing dumb, or are you really that stupid?" To "play thick" is to pretend not to understand (something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here *playing [thick](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thick)* refers to 'pretending to be  fool', so the the person is asking, "are you pretending to be a fool, or are you a fool?"

> - Informal Lacking mental agility; stupid.

(AHD)

Answer (score 3):

*Playing thick* is not an idiom: it is simply made up of colloquial meanings of the two words - *play* meaning "pretend" and *thick* meaning "stupid".

Answer (score 1):

Are you being idiotic on purpose or are you naturally that way?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic version of this that I know reverses the sentence and goes along the lines of:

"Are you *thick* (i.e. stupid), or just mucking about (i.e. messing with my mind)?"

Answer (score 1):

Thick skulled, but many times the latter isnt used.. just "being thick"

Comment: This would be a better answer if you supported it with citations.